# nginx match specific file from different folder on certain routes

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have an angularjs app, it has a blog as well. This url shows all blog posts under

```
http://example.com/blog/
```

And specific blog posts under

```
http://example.com/blog/example-blog-post-title
```

Now i'm precompiling HTML of blog posts for SEO purposes and i want to serve them completely separately from my main app like this:

```
...
root "/home/ubuntu/client/public";

location / { ## Handle default requests ##
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

location /blog { ## serve precompiled blog HTML
    alias /home/ubuntu/bloghtml;
    try_files $uri.html $uri/ index.html;
}
...
```

And this works, by going to http://example.com/blog/example-blog-post-title nginx successfully serves file /home/ubuntu/bloghtml/example-blog-post-title.html

However the issue is that in this case nginx doesn't correctly route blog post list under http://example.com/blog/ to my main angular app, i get error 403 on that URL.

I tried changing `location /blog` to `location /blog/` in conf file, this makes the http://example.com/blog/ work, howewever i get 404 errors on http://example.com/blog/example-blog-post-title

How can i make this work for both cases?

Comment: [If I understand you correctly]

If you are URL contains /blog (for example: http://example.com/blog/some-post.html) will always be served from /home/ubuntu/bloghtml root. If you want to forward the requests to your angular app, you may need to pic a different location directive for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the location from `/blog` to `/blog/` you need to remember to change alias from `/home/ubuntu/bloghtml` to `/home/ubuntu/bloghtml/`. The alias and location need to have the same ending, otherwise the calculated pathnames are wrong.

I try to avoid using `alias` and `try_files` in the same block because of [some known issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). You might consider making the last directory in the path `blog` so that you can use `root` instead.

---

I presume that your angular app is `/index.html`, in which case your `try_files` statement is incorrect. The `$url/` will cause it to try `/blog/index.html` (assuming you have an `index` directive in force) and `index.html` is missing a leading `/`.

I would suggest you try:

```
location /blog {
    alias /home/ubuntu/bloghtml;
    try_files $uri.html /index.html;
}
```

but consider designing out the `alias` directive too.